# Want to scrape coinmarketcap but am only getting first 10 currency of 100

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want scrape by this code but i get just first 10 currency in the page but the page contain 100 currincy , wheres the other 90?

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as S
import requests

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup = S(r.content,'html.parser')

price = soup.find_all('td')

for coin in soup.find_all(class_="sc-1teo54s-2 fZIJcI"):
    print(coin) ```
````

Comment: I would recommend you to use [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/pricing/) to obtain the data. First 10K calls are for free. The way you're scraping the data is not stable because class name `sc-1teo54s-2 fZIJcI` is auto-generated every time they deploy a new change.

Comment: but what's the problem for python when it not show all page contain ?

Comment: You need to scroll down up to the footer first so it loads all the data then you can scrape the data you need. See my answer below and accept it if I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

CoinMarketCap website lazy loads the data when you scroll down. This mean that if you want to scrape all shown cryptocurrencies data you need to scroll down the page up to the bottom first.

BeautifulSoup doesn't allow you to scroll down the page so you would need to use a WebDriver like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get 100 results.

```
import requests

link = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/listing'

params = {
    'start': 1,
    'limit': 100,
    'sortBy': 'market_cap',
    'sortType': 'desc',
    'convert': 'USD,BTC,ETH',
    'cryptoType': 'all',
    'tagType': 'all',
    'audited': 'false',
    'aux': 'ath,atl,high24h,low24h,num_market_pairs,cmc_rank,date_added,tags,platform,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply,volume_7d,volume_30d'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    for item in res.json()['data']['cryptoCurrencyList']:
        rank = item['cmcRank']
        coin_name = item['name']
        print(rank,coin_name)
```

Output are like (truncated):

```
1 Bitcoin
2 Ethereum
3 Tether
4 Binance Coin
5 Cardano
6 Dogecoin
7 XRP
8 USD Coin
9 Polkadot
10 Binance USD
11 Uniswap
12 Solana
13 Bitcoin Cash
14 Litecoin
15 Chainlink
16 Polygon
17 Wrapped Bitcoin
18 Ethereum Classic
19 THETA
20 Internet Computer
```

Comment: Did you try the script @data data? What's the feedback?